# Angular 2 .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

first for all i will say im a rookie in `.htaccess` and `redirects`.

The thing is, i have an angular 2 app working perfectly, but before that i was using some `.php` files to upload images to my server. But after i upload my `.htaccess` to solve the routes problem. Those `.php` are not working anymore.

This is my current `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /home/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(upload|upload_cover)\.php
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Im not able to find a solution :(.

Tree

```
  /
    -.htaccess
    -images/
    --content/
    -upload.php
    -main.bundle.js
    -inline.bundle.js
    -index.html
    -main/
```

Comment: Can you still request `upload.php` (by manually making POST/GET request) without being redirected? What exactly does *"Those .php are not working anymore."* mean?

Comment: @dfsq it means, when i put this url `http://www.mypage.com/upload.php`, the browser give me this error **Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'upload.php'**

And before upload the `.htaccess` to solve the routes problem this was working perfect.

Comment: Could you please explain which paths should be redirected to `/index.html`? Everything except `/upload.php` and `/upload_cover.php?`

Comment: I only wants `upload|upload_cover` to not be redirected when i send a file to both files.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this simplified `.htaccess`? It redirects everything except when there is a matching directory or file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried this, but doesn't work. Before end works this file return me a file name and now just return an html code. Is like the redirect is redirecting the .php files to home

Comment: Can you confirm that when you remove the `.htaccess` file your `download.php` works again?

Comment: without the `.htaccess`file works again, i will try the last code edit

Comment: with the last edit gives me this error

` Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403`

when i call upload.php

Comment: Is the location of your angular app `/home/index.html`?

Comment: just `/home`, i mean, when i put my website in the browser automatically redirect me to /home

Comment: But the file is index.html? located in the /home/ directory?

Comment: Is this .htacces placed in the webroot directory or the webroot/home directory?

Comment: Yes it's. in the root of /home

Comment: with the last edit give me this error

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.`

When i try to send a file to upload.php from my localhost

Comment: Could you please provide a file tree of your webroot?

Comment: OK. For upload you use URL `http://www.mypage.com/upload.php` and for webApp `http://www.mypage.com/home`, right? If that is the case I see no reason why my latest edit should not work.

Comment: For upload you use URL `http://www.mypage.com/upload.php` and for webApp `http://www.mypage.com/` but my main route in angular is `home` so it redirects automatically to `http://www.mypage.com/home`. I tried all the examples, this is giving me headache :)

Comment: What is redirecting you to home?

Comment: I guess the angullar 2 router component, but i think the .htaccess is individual and isn't related wit this

Comment: I just made my last edit. if it still does not work I give up.